# domain property value changes after a call to withNewSession

Tags: grails

Below is a part of code where the discrepancy is seen. The problem that i am scratching my head over is this.  I am confused over why the state of a registration changes from Active to Inactive after leaving the withNewSession block.

```
Transaction.withNewSession{ session ->
   if (saleId?.isLong()){
      invoices = registrationService.completeSale(saleId.toLong(), transactionResponse)
   }

   println Registration.last().status    //ACTIVE
}
```

println Registration.last().status //INACTIVE

The following part is optional but just for reference i have pasted it. One thing the completeSale method does is it calls the following method which will activate registrations.

```
void activateRegistrations(SaleInvoice invoice){
   Assert.notNull(invoice, 'SaleInvoice cannot be null when activating registrations.')
   List<Registration> registrations = this.findRegistrationsBySaleInvoice(invoice)
   registrations.each{
      it.status = EntityStatus.ACTIVE
      it.save()
   }
}
```

Now, my doubt is why the first println statement i.e println Registration.last().status    //ACTIVE will print ACTIVE and the second will print INACTIVE. I am guessing the Transaction.withNewSession has to do with it since the change happens in the boundary of
the withNewSession block. How can withNewSession be responsible for this apparent discrepancy?

Comment: could the fact that the integration tests run on a transaction have to do anything with this discrepancy?

Comment: Should this not be Registration.withNewSession ? what is Transaction.withNewSession. (not something I seen before)  also try .save(flush:true) as a test to see if that makes a difference